# Apply vertical alpha gradient to UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsarray, linear-gradients

I'm new to iOS development and am trying to learn Swift. I'd like to apply a vertical alpha gradient to a UITableView, but am having some trouble.

Originally following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614691/fade-out-scrolling-uitextview-over-image/24614780#24614780), I did the following:

```
var gradientMaskLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientMaskLayer.frame = myTableView.bounds
gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.05]
myTableView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
```

After getting the error `Array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C` and reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113354/swift-array-element-cannot-be-bridged-to-objective-c) I modified the two arrays used:

```
var gradientMaskLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientMaskColors:NSArray = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
var gradientMaskLocations:NSArray = [0.0, 0.05]
gradientMaskLayer.frame = myTableView.bounds
gradientMaskLayer.colors = gradientMaskColors
gradientMaskLayer.locations = gradientMaskLocations
myTableView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
```

And now get the error `Value failed to bridge from Swift type to a Objective-C type`

I'm struggling to find a solution. Can any lend some assistance?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should mask the `superview`, not the view itself.

Here's an example:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

gradient.frame = tableView.superview?.bounds ?? .null
gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.15, 0.25, 0.75, 0.85, 1.0]
tableView.superview?.layer.mask = gradient

tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

**Result:**

[image: Mask + TableView]

You can change the **orientation** by changing the `startPoint` and `endpoint` properties. The default values (vertically) are (0.5, 0.0) and (0.5, 1) respectively. Point (0,0) is the bottom-left corner of the layer and (1,1) is the top-right corner. For example, if you want to apply that mask horizontally instead of vertically, just do:

```
gradient.startPoint = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = .init(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
```

One more thing: if you're using **AutoLayout**, then you need to update the layer with the correct `CGRect` value. I usually override `layoutSubviews()` method to update it like `gradient.frame = tableView.superview?.bounds ?? .null`.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559743/how-to-mask-uiviews-in-ios/37126287#37126287 for another Swift example.

Comment: This doesn't work iOS 12 / Xcode 10.3. Results in a black gradient overlay.

Comment: You need to put the table view in a containerview that sits on top of existing content, otherwise, the superview will basically be the main view, which will reveal whatever background color you have.

Answer (score 4):

So I believe I have a solution to your problem, but I'm not sure that I fully understand it. The problem seems to arise when you try to create an implicitly unwrapped `AnyObject` array, containing *only* implicitly unwrapped Core Foundation types, i.e.:

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor:CGColor! = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
let implicitlyUnwrappedAnyObjectArray:[AnyObject]! = [implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor]
```

gives the `array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C` error.

It feels like this must be a Swift compiler issue, particularly as the following, where the implicitly unwrapped `CGColor` is declared as an implicitly unwrapped `AnyObject`, seems to make the compiler happy again:

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor:AnyObject! = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
let implicitlyUnwrappedAnyObjectArray:[AnyObject]! = [implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor]
```

as does sticking a standard Objective-C object into the array:

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor:CGColor! = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
let uiColor = UIColor.clearColor()
let implicitlyUnwrappedAnyObjectArray:[AnyObject]! = [implicitlyUnwrappedCGColor, uiColor]
```

In any case, try the following as a solution to your issue:

```
var gradientMaskLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientMaskLayer.frame = myTableView.bounds
gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor!, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor!]
gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.05]
myTableView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
```