# How to create gradient Shadow like below image(above green colour button):

Tags: ios, swift

Please check this image and give me some example to draw this shadow above green button.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a shadow. I see a button which background is a gradient from white to green (or reverse) and which title is white and not readable. What shadow are you talking about?

Comment: You likely want to use a gradient mask. Just search for `uiview gradient mask` and you'll find many examples / discussions.

Comment: @Larme: Now you can check, i have updated screen image

Comment: @DonMag Now you can check, i have updated screen image

Comment: I don't think the white fade is part of the button. It seems to be part of the content container, because it also affects the price and name of the product.

Comment: @2C-B: This is gradient mask. Please give me some example

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary - based on the image, it looks like a gradient mask has been applied either to the table itself, or a "clear-to-white" gradient on a view on top of the table. Take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418022/6257435