# iOS fade to black at top of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cagradientlayer

I have a `UITableView` where my cell `backgroundView` is a `UIImageView`. I would like top of each image to fade to black so I can overlay some white text.

I have looked at some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614691/fade-out-scrolling-uitextview-over-image), but none seem to be working.

In `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` I have tried:

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

var gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = imageView.frame
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.clearColor()]
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.1]
imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

cell!.backgroundView = imageView
```

But I see no gradient and no difference from when I remove the gradient code. Is my gradient sitting under the image?

If I replace the line `imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)` with `imageView.layer.mask = gradient` then my cells are just blank and white (no image anymore).

Comment: I'm the poster of the answer you linked to. Please note that `gradient.colors` should contain `CGColor`s and not  `UIColor`s.

Comment: Congrat to 3k ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `gradient.colors` you need to have array of `CGColor`, so:

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor]
```

Comment: Oh, he was using UIColors, wasn't he? Good catch. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

I forget how the layers array is ordered. However, you should just add your gradient layer on top of your image view's layer using addSubLayer, not insertSublayer:atIndex: You want the gradient layer on top of the other layer so that it's non-opaque parts cover the image view.

Comment: Both work for me with the CGColor fix from the accepted answer, but yes, addSubLayer is definitely more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.0, some slight tweaks required:

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = imageView.frame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.1]
    imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```