# UITextView fade beginning and end of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have seen many times that a text view is faded in/out at the beginning/end of the text area. Is this a built in function in iOS or do you make it manually? And how?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the example textfield that your referred to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614691/fade-out-scrolling-uitextview-over-image